# What is the difference between `char **argv` and `char** argv`?

Tags: c++

I have the two following C++ `main` function headers:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)

int main(int argc, char** argv)
```

I know that the asterisk `*` signifies a pointer, but I do not understand the difference between these two. The one I usually see is `char **argv`, which, If I'm not mistaken, declares `argv` to be a pointer to a pointer to a char. If so, then what is `char** argv`?

Comment: There is no difference, It is just a readability difference. The first one states to be better.

Comment: When C devs are around we act like `char **argv` is totally valid and oh, PLEASE, do tell us for the 10th time how things were when you developed on a 8088 IBM PC... But deep down C++ devs know `*` is an information about the type, and therefore it belongs to the left side of the "TYPE NAME;" declaration format.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> If so, then what is char** argv?

If (also) declares `argv` to be a pointer to a pointer to a char.

> What is the difference between `char **argv` and `char** argv`?

The difference between them is the placement of space. There is no other difference. These are also the same:

```
char**argv

char                         *  *   argv

char
*
*
argv
```

Comment: Check Stroustrup's FAQ entry on this topic: https://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#whitespace